# Creating a xslt transformation based based on effective dates and sequence

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I  have the following xml file. I need to be able to generate a csv file based on below. However the catch is if its the same effective moment and there are multiple sequence attributes it should generate just one line of output, however if the effective moment (just date part) is different then it should generate a line each based on the effective moment. I have trying to play with xslt but have been struggling so far. Any help provided will be appreciated.

XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<peci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:peci="urn:com.w/peci">
<peci:Worker>
    <peci:Summary>
        <peci:Integration_Event>14d964101fdb0156e164341b45548d01</peci:Integration_Event>
        <peci:Integration_Sent_On>2018-05-10T08:41:39.375-07:00</peci:Integration_Sent_On>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_Name>West Brooke - Biweekly: B</peci:Payroll_Company_Name>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Country>US</peci:Pay_Group_Country>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Code>j</peci:Pay_Group_Code>
        <peci:Pay_Period_Start>2018-04-30-07:00</peci:Pay_Period_Start>
        <peci:Pay_Period_End>2018-05-13-07:00</peci:Pay_Period_End>
        <peci:Updated_From>2018-05-07T19:50:30.963-07:00</peci:Updated_From>
        <peci:Updated_To>2018-05-10T08:41:39.375-07:00</peci:Updated_To>
        <peci:Effective_From>2018-04-30-07:00</peci:Effective_From>
        <peci:Effective_To>2018-05-13-07:00</peci:Effective_To>
        <peci:Change_Detection>Include only changes entered since the last successful run.</peci:Change_Detection>
        <peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>0</peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>
        <peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>0</peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>
        <peci:Full_Snapshot>0</peci:Full_Snapshot>
        <peci:Worker_Count>2</peci:Worker_Count>
        <peci:Version>1</peci:Version>
    </peci:Summary>
    <peci:Worker>
        <peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:WID>rd</peci:WID>
            <peci:Employee_ID>33333</peci:Employee_ID>
            <peci:Name>Test 1</peci:Name>
        </peci:Worker_Summary>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2018-05-10T08:29:21.235-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2018-05-10T08:29:21.235-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Worker_Status>
                <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>
                <peci:Active>1</peci:Active>
                <peci:Active_Status_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                <peci:Hire_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Hire_Date>
                <peci:Original_Hire_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Original_Hire_Date>
                <peci:Is_Rehire>0</peci:Is_Rehire>
                <peci:Continuous_Service_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Continuous_Service_Date>
                <peci:First_Day_of_Work>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:First_Day_of_Work>
                <peci:Seniority_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Seniority_Date>
            </peci:Worker_Status>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="1">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2018-05-10T08:31:27.880-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2018-05-10T08:31:27.880-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Worker_Status>
                <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>
                <peci:Active>1</peci:Active>
                <peci:Active_Status_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                <peci:Hire_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Hire_Date>
                <peci:Original_Hire_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Original_Hire_Date>
                <peci:Is_Rehire>0</peci:Is_Rehire>
                <peci:Continuous_Service_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Continuous_Service_Date>
                <peci:First_Day_of_Work>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:First_Day_of_Work>
                <peci:Seniority_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Seniority_Date>
            </peci:Worker_Status>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
                <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="2">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2018-05-12T08:29:21.235-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2018-05-12T08:29:21.235-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Worker_Status>
                <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>
                <peci:Active>1</peci:Active>
                <peci:Active_Status_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                <peci:Hire_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Hire_Date>
                <peci:Original_Hire_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Original_Hire_Date>
                <peci:Is_Rehire>0</peci:Is_Rehire>
                <peci:Continuous_Service_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Continuous_Service_Date>
                <peci:First_Day_of_Work>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:First_Day_of_Work>
                <peci:Seniority_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Seniority_Date>
            </peci:Worker_Status>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
    </peci:Worker>
</peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
```

**Desired Output:**
3333,2018-10-05,Active
3333,2018-10-10,Active

Comment: could you provide also an example where you expect several lines in your csv file? Also could you explain how are the dates extracted?

Comment: Xml looks malformed or incomplete?

Comment: The desired output shows dates `2018-10-05` and `2018-10-10` which are not present in the input XML. Which dates do these correspond to and are they in a different format?

Comment: You need to specify which version of XSLT this is. XSLT 2.0 has rich capability for date-and-time handling which is missing from 1.0.

Comment: Furthermore this is a grouping problem (you want to group elements with the same "effective moment"). Grouping in 2.0 is handled using xsl:for-each-group, in 1.0 it is done using the Muenchian method. Both are extensively covered in books, tutorials, and previous StackOverflow answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- you can use XSLT 2.0,
- the output should contain separate row for each `Effective_Moment` (date
  part), for each employee,

you can do the task the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:peci="urn:com.w/peci" xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.w/peci">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="Workers_Effective_Stack">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker/Effective_Change" group-by=
      "concat(../Worker_Summary/Employee_ID, substring(Effective_Moment,1,10))">
      <xsl:value-of select="../Worker_Summary/Employee_ID"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(Effective_Moment, 1, 10)"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Worker_Status/Status"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Caution: Your source XML has one unbalanced `peci:Worker` opening tag, I deleted them.

Note: It is possible to perform grouping solely by the effective date,
but I think is not what you want. If your input contained a number of
effective changes for different employees, but on the same effective date,
then the output would have contained only one record from this group.
This is why I performed grouping using a composite key, including also the
employee ID.