# XSLT : Create one row for each element in output file

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a requirement where I need to create a csv file using xslt 1.0/2.0.
In below Source XML - For each complex type element inside <Effective_Change>, In this case it is <Worker_Status> I need to create a row for each child element inside complex type element.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <peci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:peci="urn:com.w/peci">
    <peci:Worker>
        <peci:Summary>
            <peci:Integration_Event>14d964101fdb0156e164341b45548d01</peci:Integration_Event>
            <peci:Integration_Sent_On>2018-05-10T08:41:39.375-07:00</peci:Integration_Sent_On>
            <peci:Payroll_Company_Name>West Brooke - Biweekly: B</peci:Payroll_Company_Name>
            <peci:Pay_Group_Country>US</peci:Pay_Group_Country>
        </peci:Summary>
        <peci:Worker>
            <peci:Worker_Summary>
                <peci:WID>rd</peci:WID>
                <peci:Employee_ID>33333</peci:Employee_ID>
                <peci:Name>Test 1</peci:Name>
            </peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2018-05-10T08:29:21.235-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2018-05-10T08:29:21.235-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
                <peci:Worker_Status>
                    <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>
                    <peci:Active>1</peci:Active>
                    <peci:Active_Status_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                    <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                    <peci:Hire_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Hire_Date>
                    <peci:Original_Hire_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Original_Hire_Date>
                    <peci:Is_Rehire>0</peci:Is_Rehire>
                    <peci:Continuous_Service_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Continuous_Service_Date>
                    <peci:First_Day_of_Work>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:First_Day_of_Work>
                    <peci:Seniority_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Seniority_Date>
                </peci:Worker_Status>
            </peci:Effective_Change>
            <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="1">
                <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
                <peci:Effective_Moment>2018-05-10T08:31:27.880-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
                <peci:Entry_Moment>2018-05-10T08:31:27.880-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
                <peci:Worker_Status>
                    <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>
                    <peci:Active>1</peci:Active>
                    <peci:Active_Status_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                    <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                    <peci:Hire_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Hire_Date>
                    <peci:Original_Hire_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Original_Hire_Date>
                    <peci:Is_Rehire>0</peci:Is_Rehire>
                    <peci:Continuous_Service_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Continuous_Service_Date>
                    <peci:First_Day_of_Work>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:First_Day_of_Work>
                    <peci:Seniority_Date>2018-01-08-08:00</peci:Seniority_Date>
                </peci:Worker_Status>
    
        </peci:Worker>
    </peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
```

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<peci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    <peci:Summary>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_ID>Test Company</peci:Payroll_Company_ID>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_Name>Test Company</peci:Payroll_Company_Name>
        <peci:Pay_Group_ID>Monthly</peci:Pay_Group_ID>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Name>Test</peci:Pay_Group_Name>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Country>SE</peci:Pay_Group_Country>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Code>3</peci:Pay_Group_Code>
        <peci:Pay_Period_Start>2017-03-01-03.34</peci:Pay_Period_Start>
        <peci:Pay_Period_End>2017-03-30-03.34</peci:Pay_Period_End>
        <peci:Updated_From>2017-03-10T07:56:16.000-03.34</peci:Updated_From>
        <peci:Updated_To>2017-03-19T09:06:13.769-03.34</peci:Updated_To>
        <peci:Effective_From>2017-03-01-03.34</peci:Effective_From>
        <peci:Effective_To>2017-03-30-03.34</peci:Effective_To>
        <peci:Change_Detection>Test</peci:Change_Detection>
        <peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>0</peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>
        <peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>1</peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>
        <peci:Full_Snapshot>0</peci:Full_Snapshot>
        <peci:Worker_Count>1</peci:Worker_Count>
        <peci:Version>1</peci:Version>
    </peci:Summary>
    <peci:Worker>
        <peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:WID>2232</peci:WID>
            <peci:Employee_ID>1141</peci:Employee_ID>
            <peci:Name>Andrew D Johnson</peci:Name>
        </peci:Worker_Summary>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>HIR</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2017-03-11T04:51:00.632-03.34</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Worker_Status peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Status peci:isAdded="1">Active</peci:Status>
                <peci:Active peci:priorValue="0">1</peci:Active>
                <peci:Active_Status_Date peci:isAdded="1">2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                <peci:Hire_Date peci:isAdded="1">2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Hire_Date>
                <peci:Original_Hire_Date peci:isAdded="1">2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Original_Hire_Date>
                <peci:Hire_Rescinded>0</peci:Hire_Rescinded>
                <peci:Is_Rehire>0</peci:Is_Rehire>
                <peci:End_Employment_Date peci:isAdded="1">2021-05-31-03.34</peci:End_Employment_Date>
            </peci:Worker_Status>
            <peci:Personal peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Legal_Name peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:First_Name>Andrew</peci:First_Name>
                    <peci:Middle_Name>D</peci:Middle_Name>
                    <peci:Last_Name>Johnson</peci:Last_Name>
                </peci:Legal_Name>
                <peci:Workday_Account peci:isAdded="1">1141</peci:Workday_Account>
            </peci:Personal>
            <peci:Person_Communication peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Email peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Email_Address>adjohnson@gmail.com</peci:Email_Address>
                </peci:Email>
            </peci:Person_Communication>
            <peci:Person_Identification peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:National_Identifier peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:National_ID>2037203020</peci:National_ID>
                    <peci:National_ID_Type>DL</peci:National_ID_Type>
                </peci:National_Identifier>
            </peci:Person_Identification>
            <peci:Position peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Worker_Type>Fixed_Term</peci:Worker_Type>
                <peci:Position_Time_Type>Full_time</peci:Position_Time_Type>
                <peci:Job_Exempt>0</peci:Job_Exempt>
                <peci:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>40</peci:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>
                <peci:Default_Weekly_Hours>40</peci:Default_Weekly_Hours>
                <peci:Pay_Rate_Type>Salaried</peci:Pay_Rate_Type>
                <peci:Job_Classification>
                    <peci:Job_Classification_Group>FT</peci:Job_Classification_Group>
                    <peci:Job_Classification_ID>232</peci:Job_Classification_ID>
                </peci:Job_Classification>
                <peci:Management_Level>AL1</peci:Management_Level>
                <peci:Job_Category>TA</peci:Job_Category>
                <peci:Business_Site>
                    <peci:Location_ID>CA_001</peci:Location_ID>
                </peci:Business_Site>
                <peci:Supervisor>
                    <peci:ID>1139</peci:ID>
                    <peci:Name>David Brown</peci:Name>
                </peci:Supervisor>
                <peci:Probation_Start_Date>2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Probation_Start_Date>
                <peci:Probation_End_Date>2020-07-10-03.34</peci:Probation_End_Date>
            </peci:Position>
            <peci:Compensation peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
                    <peci:Total_Base_Pay>34000</peci:Total_Base_Pay>
                    <peci:Frequency>Yearly</peci:Frequency>
                </peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
            </peci:Compensation>
            <peci:Compensation_Plans peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Salary_and_Hourly_Plan>
                    <peci:Compensation_Plan>Base_Salary</peci:Compensation_Plan>
                    <peci:Amount>34000</peci:Amount>
                    <peci:Apply_FTE>1</peci:Apply_FTE>
                    <peci:Frequency>Yearly</peci:Frequency>
                    <peci:Start_Date>2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Start_Date>
                </peci:Salary_and_Hourly_Plan>
            </peci:Compensation_Plans>
            <peci:Employee_Contract peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Start_Date>2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Start_Date>
                <peci:Contract_Status>Closed</peci:Contract_Status>
            </peci:Employee_Contract>
            <peci:Collective_Agreement peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Collective_Agreement>No</peci:Collective_Agreement>
                <peci:Collective_Agreement_Factor>
                    <peci:Factor>level</peci:Factor>
                </peci:Collective_Agreement_Factor>
                <peci:Collective_Agreement_Factor>
                    <peci:Factor>level</peci:Factor>
                </peci:Collective_Agreement_Factor>
            </peci:Collective_Agreement>
            <peci:Additional_Information>
                <peci:WorkerID>2232</peci:WorkerID>
            </peci:Additional_Information>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="1">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2017-03-11T00:00:00.000-03.34</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2017-03-11T04:47:25.190-03.34</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Person_Communication peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Address peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Address_Line_1>Address_Line_1</peci:Address_Line_1>
                    <peci:City>City</peci:City>
                    <peci:Postal_Code>32323</peci:Postal_Code>
                    <peci:Country>US</peci:Country>
                </peci:Address>
                <peci:Email>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Email_Address>adjohnson@gmail.com</peci:Email_Address>
                </peci:Email>
            </peci:Person_Communication>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
    </peci:Worker>
</peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
```

Outfile should have below format.

Derived_Event_Code,Effective_Moment,xml_element_name,xml_element_value

```
**Example output CSV file:** 

    DTA,2018-05-10,Status,Active
    DTA,2018-05-10,Active,1
    DTA,2018-05-10,Active_Status_Date,2018-01-08-08:00
    DTA,2018-05-10,Terminated,0
    DTA,2018-05-10,Hire_Date,2018-01-08-08:00
    DTA,2018-05-10,Original_Hire_Date,2018-01-08-08:00
    DTA,2018-05-10,Is_Rehire,0
    DTA,2018-05-10,Continuous_Service_Date,0
    DTA,2018-05-10,First_Day_of_Work,2018-01-08-08:00
    DTA,2018-05-10,Seniority_Date,2018-01-08-08:00
    
    DTA,2018-05-10,Status,Active
    DTA,2018-05-10,Active,1
    DTA,2018-05-10,Active_Status_Date,2018-01-08-08:00
    DTA,2018-05-10,Terminated,0
    DTA,2018-05-10,Hire_Date,2018-01-08-08:00
    DTA,2018-05-10,Original_Hire_Date,2018-01-08-08:00
    DTA,2018-05-10,Is_Rehire,0
    DTA,2018-05-10,Continuous_Service_Date,0
    DTA,2018-05-10,First_Day_of_Work,2018-01-08-08:00
    DTA,2018-05-10,Seniority_Date,2018-01-08-08:00
```

Can someone suggest me how to achieve using xslt ?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: As I understand, I would need to create a for-each loop for every element to create a output file. Is there any other way to achieve it ?

Comment: I don't think so. You can use a * wildcard with a predicate to select any complex element that is a child of `Effective_Change`. -- P.S. Can you edit your question and fix the input to be a well-formed XML?

Comment: Now sure how to edit my question. But my xml file is exactly same as posted in this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284159/creating-a-xslt-transformation-based-based-on-effective-dates-and-sequence

Comment: Click the `edit` button and proceed from there. The other file is also not well-formed XML: there is an unclosed `<peci:Worker>` tag.

Comment: Thanks Michael.. I have a added a new wel formed xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<peci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    <peci:Summary>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_ID>Test Company</peci:Payroll_Company_ID>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_Name>Test Company</peci:Payroll_Company_Name>
        <peci:Pay_Group_ID>Monthly</peci:Pay_Group_ID>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Name>Test</peci:Pay_Group_Name>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Country>SE</peci:Pay_Group_Country>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Code>3</peci:Pay_Group_Code>
        <peci:Pay_Period_Start>2017-03-01-03.34</peci:Pay_Period_Start>
        <peci:Pay_Period_End>2017-03-30-03.34</peci:Pay_Period_End>
        <peci:Updated_From>2017-03-10T07:56:16.000-03.34</peci:Updated_From>
        <peci:Updated_To>2017-03-19T09:06:13.769-03.34</peci:Updated_To>
        <peci:Effective_From>2017-03-01-03.34</peci:Effective_From>
        <peci:Effective_To>2017-03-30-03.34</peci:Effective_To>
        <peci:Change_Detection>Test</peci:Change_Detection>
        <peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>0</peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>
        <peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>1</peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>
        <peci:Full_Snapshot>0</peci:Full_Snapshot>
        <peci:Worker_Count>1</peci:Worker_Count>
        <peci:Version>1</peci:Version>
    </peci:Summary>
    <peci:Worker>
        <peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:WID>2232</peci:WID>
            <peci:Employee_ID>1141</peci:Employee_ID>
            <peci:Name>Andrew D Johnson</peci:Name>
        </peci:Worker_Summary>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>HIR</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2017-03-11T04:51:00.632-03.34</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Worker_Status peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Status peci:isAdded="1">Active</peci:Status>
                <peci:Active peci:priorValue="0">1</peci:Active>
                <peci:Active_Status_Date peci:isAdded="1">2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                <peci:Hire_Date peci:isAdded="1">2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Hire_Date>
                <peci:Original_Hire_Date peci:isAdded="1">2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Original_Hire_Date>
                <peci:Hire_Rescinded>0</peci:Hire_Rescinded>
                <peci:Is_Rehire>0</peci:Is_Rehire>
                <peci:End_Employment_Date peci:isAdded="1">2021-05-31-03.34</peci:End_Employment_Date>
            </peci:Worker_Status>
            <peci:Personal peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Legal_Name peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:First_Name>Andrew</peci:First_Name>
                    <peci:Middle_Name>D</peci:Middle_Name>
                    <peci:Last_Name>Johnson</peci:Last_Name>
                </peci:Legal_Name>
                <peci:Workday_Account peci:isAdded="1">1141</peci:Workday_Account>
            </peci:Personal>
            <peci:Person_Communication peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Email peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Email_Address>adjohnson@gmail.com</peci:Email_Address>
                </peci:Email>
            </peci:Person_Communication>
            <peci:Person_Identification peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:National_Identifier peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:National_ID>2037203020</peci:National_ID>
                    <peci:National_ID_Type>DL</peci:National_ID_Type>
                </peci:National_Identifier>
            </peci:Person_Identification>
            <peci:Position peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Worker_Type>Fixed_Term</peci:Worker_Type>
                <peci:Position_Time_Type>Full_time</peci:Position_Time_Type>
                <peci:Job_Exempt>0</peci:Job_Exempt>
                <peci:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>40</peci:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>
                <peci:Default_Weekly_Hours>40</peci:Default_Weekly_Hours>
                <peci:Pay_Rate_Type>Salaried</peci:Pay_Rate_Type>
                <peci:Job_Classification>
                    <peci:Job_Classification_Group>FT</peci:Job_Classification_Group>
                    <peci:Job_Classification_ID>232</peci:Job_Classification_ID>
                </peci:Job_Classification>
                <peci:Management_Level>AL1</peci:Management_Level>
                <peci:Job_Category>TA</peci:Job_Category>
                <peci:Business_Site>
                    <peci:Location_ID>CA_001</peci:Location_ID>
                </peci:Business_Site>
                <peci:Supervisor>
                    <peci:ID>1139</peci:ID>
                    <peci:Name>David Brown</peci:Name>
                </peci:Supervisor>
                <peci:Probation_Start_Date>2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Probation_Start_Date>
                <peci:Probation_End_Date>2020-07-10-03.34</peci:Probation_End_Date>
            </peci:Position>
            <peci:Compensation peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
                    <peci:Total_Base_Pay>34000</peci:Total_Base_Pay>
                    <peci:Frequency>Yearly</peci:Frequency>
                </peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
            </peci:Compensation>
            <peci:Compensation_Plans peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Salary_and_Hourly_Plan>
                    <peci:Compensation_Plan>Base_Salary</peci:Compensation_Plan>
                    <peci:Amount>34000</peci:Amount>
                    <peci:Apply_FTE>1</peci:Apply_FTE>
                    <peci:Frequency>Yearly</peci:Frequency>
                    <peci:Start_Date>2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Start_Date>
                </peci:Salary_and_Hourly_Plan>
            </peci:Compensation_Plans>
            <peci:Employee_Contract peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Start_Date>2017-03-10-03.34</peci:Start_Date>
                <peci:Contract_Status>Closed</peci:Contract_Status>
            </peci:Employee_Contract>
            <peci:Collective_Agreement peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Collective_Agreement>No</peci:Collective_Agreement>
                <peci:Collective_Agreement_Factor>
                    <peci:Factor>level</peci:Factor>
                </peci:Collective_Agreement_Factor>
                <peci:Collective_Agreement_Factor>
                    <peci:Factor>level</peci:Factor>
                </peci:Collective_Agreement_Factor>
            </peci:Collective_Agreement>
            <peci:Additional_Information>
                <peci:WorkerID>2232</peci:WorkerID>
            </peci:Additional_Information>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="1">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2017-03-11T00:00:00.000-03.34</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2017-03-11T04:47:25.190-03.34</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Person_Communication peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Address peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Address_Line_1>Address_Line_1</peci:Address_Line_1>
                    <peci:City>City</peci:City>
                    <peci:Postal_Code>32323</peci:Postal_Code>
                    <peci:Country>US</peci:Country>
                </peci:Address>
                <peci:Email>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Email_Address>adjohnson@gmail.com</peci:Email_Address>
                </peci:Email>
            </peci:Person_Communication>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
    </peci:Worker>
</peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/peci:Workers_Effective_Stack"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="peci:Worker/peci:Effective_Change">
        <xsl:variable name="common-data">
            <xsl:value-of select="peci:Derived_Event_Code"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>          
            <xsl:value-of select="peci:Effective_Moment"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>          
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- for every leaf descendant -->
        <xsl:for-each select="*//*[not(*)]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$common-data"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>          
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>          
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>          
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Status,Active
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Active,1
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Active_Status_Date,2017-03-10-03.34
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Terminated,0
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Hire_Date,2017-03-10-03.34
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Original_Hire_Date,2017-03-10-03.34
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Hire_Rescinded,0
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Is_Rehire,0
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,End_Employment_Date,2021-05-31-03.34
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,First_Name,Andrew
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Middle_Name,D
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Last_Name,Johnson
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Workday_Account,1141
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Usage_Type,HOME
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Email_Address,adjohnson@gmail.com
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,National_ID,2037203020
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,National_ID_Type,DL
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Worker_Type,Fixed_Term
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Position_Time_Type,Full_time
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Job_Exempt,0
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Scheduled_Weekly_Hours,40
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Default_Weekly_Hours,40
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Pay_Rate_Type,Salaried
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Job_Classification_Group,FT
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Job_Classification_ID,232
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Management_Level,AL1
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Job_Category,TA
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Location_ID,CA_001
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,ID,1139
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Name,David Brown
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Probation_Start_Date,2017-03-10-03.34
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Probation_End_Date,2020-07-10-03.34
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Total_Base_Pay,34000
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Frequency,Yearly
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Compensation_Plan,Base_Salary
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Amount,34000
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Apply_FTE,1
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Frequency,Yearly
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Start_Date,2017-03-10-03.34
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Start_Date,2017-03-10-03.34
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Contract_Status,Closed
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Collective_Agreement,No
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Factor,level
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,Factor,level
HIR,2017-03-10T00:00:00.000-03.34,WorkerID,2232

DTA,2017-03-11T00:00:00.000-03.34,Usage_Type,HOME
DTA,2017-03-11T00:00:00.000-03.34,Address_Line_1,Address_Line_1
DTA,2017-03-11T00:00:00.000-03.34,City,City
DTA,2017-03-11T00:00:00.000-03.34,Postal_Code,32323
DTA,2017-03-11T00:00:00.000-03.34,Country,US
DTA,2017-03-11T00:00:00.000-03.34,Usage_Type,HOME
DTA,2017-03-11T00:00:00.000-03.34,Email_Address,adjohnson@gmail.com
```